# Insertar múltiples registros en MySQL con PDO a través del patrón MVC

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

Estoy tratando de insertar múltiples registros en MySQL con PDO a través del patrón MVC, pero al abrir la vista me aparece la respuesta "No se han enviado los datos" y al intentar enviar los registros, no se almacenan en la base de datos. Que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta?

Esto es lo que tengo de ejemplo:

**Tabla MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `valor`.`prueba` 
( `documento` INT(15) NOT NULL , `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Vista:**

```
<?php 
    require_once "controlador.php";
    require_once "modelo.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form role="form" method="post">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) :?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="documento[]">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre[]">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </tbody>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar">
            <?php
                $ingresarDatos = new ControladorDatos();
                $ingresarDatos -> ctrIngresarDato();
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controlador:**

```
<?php
class ControladorDatos {
    static public function ctrIngresarDato(){
        if (isset($_POST["documento"])) {

            $tabla = "prueba";
            $datos = array("documento" => $_POST["documento"], "nombre" => $_POST["nombre"]);

            $respuesta = ModeloDatos::mdlIngresarDatos($tabla, $datos);

            if ($respuesta == "ok") {
                echo "Se han insertado los datos";
            } else {
                echo "No se han insertado los datos";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Modelo:**

```
<?php
class Conexion{
    static public function conectar(){
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=valor","root","");
        $link -> exec("set names utf8");
        return $link;
    }
}

class ModeloDatos{
    static public function mdlIngresarDatos($tabla, $datos){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(documento, nombre) VALUES (:documento, :nombre)");

        foreach ($datos as $value) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":documento", $value["documento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $value["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return "ok";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: La etiqueta form no tiene asociada ninguna acción. Al realizar submit deberías llamar el archivo PHP que se encarga de agregar los datos.

Comment: Agrega en tu conexion las propiedades de   $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); para visualizar los posibles errores que contenga, y tambien utiliza los try catch

Comment: Fijate como estas pasando los datos, cuando llegas a `bindParam(":documento", $datos["documento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);` la variable `$datos["documento"]` es un array que contiene los 2 datos de los dos campos del dformulario en lugar de un string  como espera. `$datos` es un array de arrays, no de string. debes recorrerlo para ingresar las diferentes filas.

Comment: A todos gracias por responder. @Xerif entonces debe ser con un ciclo?... de ser así, en el ciclo debo incluir el bindParam y el excecute?... o como debería escribirlo?. Perdón si es algo obvio, pero apenas estoy conociendo MVC y PDO. He buscado en Internet pero no encuentro algo que me oriente hasta ahora.

Comment: No estoy seguro pero por lo que veo en tu form ni en ningún lado tienes una url o en el caso del form un `action`para que sea a que ruta debe ir.

Comment: @pavlob @jemonge tengo entendido que los `form` en `MVC` no utilizan el atributo `action`. Tengo varios formularios que insertan un solo registro en la base de datos y están funcionando sin este atributo, para eso se invoca `require_once "controlador.php";` y `require_once "modelo.php";` al inicio de la vista _(en los archivos ejemplo)_. El problema que tengo es con las inserciones múltiples que vienen de tablas HTML.

Comment: Si estoy equivocado, por favor me corrigen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualmente cuando envias el formulario al método `ModeloDatos::mdlIngresarDatos()` le llega un array tal que así:

```
$datos = array(
    'documento' => array('documento1', 'documento2'),
    'nombre' => array('nombre1', 'nombre2')
);
```

Por lo que cuando ejecutas los `bindParam()` estas pasando un array en lugar de un string y se intenta hacer la conversion.

Para para solucionar esto podemos realizarlo de varias formas, construir un query con los la misma cantidad de datos a insertar es decir algo así, es mas laborioso de realizar aun que mas eficiente:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (documento, nombre) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)...
```

Ejecutar la consulta tantas veces como nesitemos con los diferentes valores, pero preparando la consulta una unica vez, facil de realizar y bastante eficiente

Por ejemplo

Editando `ModeloDatos::mdlIngresarDatos`

```
static public function mdlIngresarDatos($tabla, $datos){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(documento, nombre) VALUES (:documento, :nombre)");

    // Recorremos los valores del array datos['documentos']
    // para determinar cuantas filas hay
    foreach($datos["documento"] as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":documento", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // paramos $key $datos["nombre"] para obtener el nombre
        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    return "ok";
}
```

<sub>**Nota:** En este ejemplo no se esta controlando la inserción de los registros adecuadamente, por lo que si alguno de los insert falla los que se hayan ejecutado enteriormente de forma correcta quedaran insertados. Para evitar este comportamiente se deberían utilizar transacciones.</sub>

Tambien si `ModeloDatos::mdlIngresarDatos()` es reutilizado múltiples veces y no te interesa que se ejecuten el foreach dentro, otra opción podría ser hacer el ciclo en `ctrIngresarDato()` preparando y ejecutando la consulta por cada registro. La menos eficiente.

Por cual decantarde, es un poco cuestion de tus necesidades, no es lo mismo si sienpre van a ser bloques de 2 rows o por el contrario pueden ser bloques de decenas de rows.

Comment: Intenté con el `foreach` tal como lo sugieres pero sigo obteniendo el mismo comportamiento, no inserta los datos y no muestra error. En el proyecto real, aunque la estructura es similar, la cantidad de filas es variable, por esa razón no puedo pasarle marcadores de posición fijos. Tienes alguna sugerencia adicional?

Comment: @DjCrazy Puesdes hacer un `print_r()` a `$datos` o `$_POST` y añadirlo a la pregunta para ver cual es la estructura. Por otro lado indicas que no te genera ningun error, no obstante, te retorna `ok` o `error`

Comment: Con ciertas modificaciones al código _que ya están editadas en la pregunta y siguiendo tus indicaciones_ al hacer `print_r($datos);` muestra esto: `Array ( [documento] => Array ( [0] => 1040356985 [1] => 1125563852 ) [nombre] => Array ( [0] => Jhon Doe [1] => Ali Prime ) )`. Pero seguidamente muestra _No se han insertado los datos_

Comment: @DjCrazy El `prepare` te retorna un objeto o `false`? Se inserta en la base de datos? Te da algun error, ya sea al ejecutarlo o en el log? Fijate que en mi ejemplo cambie el condicional que hay despues del bucle foreach y que el bucle debe incluir tambien el execute(), no solo los bindParam().

Comment: Correcto, funciona justo como lo planteas... Incluso funciona con el código de la pregunta, pero incluyendo el `if` en el `foreach`. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo!

Comment: @DjCrazy Lo que pasa con el `if` tal como lo planteas en la pregunta es que si la insercion es correcta, hara un `return "ok";` que terminara la ejecucion del metodo antes de tiempo, por este motivo, se dejo el retorno solo en caso de error dentro del bucle y el ok fuera de el, para que se retone una vez que se han realizado todos los insert.

Comment: Comprendo. Así lo haré entonces. Gracias por la claridad!