# UPDATE array's con multiples indices

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

como le hago para actualizar dos o mas registros relacionados a un ID?. Puedo consultar la informacion y ponerla en inputs para poder editarla. Los nombres de los inputs, les pongo corchetes seguidos del nombre "nombre[]", para poder enviarlos como array por $_POST:

```
<td width="5%">
    <input type="text" id="id_partida" name="id_partida[]" 
   value="<?php echo $presupuesto['id_partida']; ?>" class="form-control">
</td>

<td width="5%">
       <input type="text" id="partida" name="partida[]" value="<?php echo $i++; ?>"
       class="form-control">
</td>

<td width="50%" style="text-align: justify;">
     <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion[]" style="width: 100%;"
     value="<?php echo $presupuesto['descripcion'], $presupuesto['material'] ;?>">
</td>

<td width="5%">
     <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"
     value="<?php echo $presupuesto['cantidad'] ;?>">
</td>

<td width="15%"><span>$</span>
      <input type="text" id="precio_unitario" name="precio_unitario[]"
      style="width: 50%; text-align: center;"
      value="<?php echo number_format($presupuesto['precio_unitario'],2) ;?>">
 </td>
```

Pero al revisar con un print_r($_POST), si recibo el array y sus respectivos datos, incluso si tiene mas 1 indice

```
echo '<pre>';

[descripcion] => Array
        (
            [0] => SOLERA, MATERIAL ACERO INOXIDABLE, MATERIAL ACERO INOXIDABLE
            [1] => PLACA, MATERIAL ALUMINIO, MATERIAL ALUMINIO
        )
```

y al mandarlo para UPDATE, dependiendo el index que ponga como parametro, es el registro que se actualiza.

```
$sql ="UPDATE presupuestos_partidas SET descripcion=:descripcion, cantidad=:cantidad, precio_unitario=:precio_unitario,
        importe=:importe WHERE id_partida = :id_partida";
$sql_run = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sql_exec = $sql_run->execute(array(":descripcion"=>$descripcion[1], ":cantidad"=>$cantidad[1],":precio_unitario"=>$precio_unitario[1],
                                    ":importe"=>$importe[1],":id_partida"=>$id_partida[1]));
```

Si en el indice pongo 0 [0], pues me actualiza el registro que este en ese indice, pero como le hago para me actualize todo lo que hay en ese array[descripcion], con todos sus indices. Agradezco mucho la ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: tenes que ejecutar un update por set de datos.. o sea, ejecuta otro update con los otros datos

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar, una disculpa pero no explique el contexto del programa. El programa es para cotizar, entonces puede que en veces solo se cotize un producto y ahi no hay problema, pero habra ocaciones en que se cotizen mas de 2 productos, por que necesito saber como "englobar" todo el array, sin importar si son 1 o n cantidad de indices.

Comment: Me suena a que le estás tirando a PHP un problema a resolver en la base de datos, programando un disparador (TRIGGER). Sea como sea, al leer la pregunta no se entiende con claridad cuál es el problema concretamente. ¿Cómo debe ser la consulta `UPDATE` que requieres, qué criterios debe tener, etc?

Comment: Pues el programa es para cotizar. Ya puedo guardar la cotizacion usando tablas relacionadas. Puedo consultar y traerme de la BDD la informacion y ponerla en un formulario para poder editar. Por ejemplo, si en una cotizacion #3 hay 3 productos, con sus respectivas cantidades y precio unitario, puedo eliminar el producto individualmente y ese registro se elimina de la BDD. Pero si quiero editar el producto, o sea la fila donde esta ese producto (nombre, cantidad, etc), solo me actualiza el indice que le indique en el query.

Comment: no termino de entender tu problema.. no sabes como iterar tu array para ejecutar varias veces el query con cada fila de datos?

Comment: si, no se como expresarlo con codigo, para que recorra el array y se vaya actualizando en la BDD, segun las cantidades de indices que tenga cada array.

Comment: Tal vez la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224456/insertar-m%c3%baltiples-registros-en-mysql-con-pdo-a-trav%c3%a9s-del-patr%c3%b3n-mvc) te pueda ayudar, es una sentencia `insert`, pero la función es similar para una sentencia `update`.

Comment: Ya lo "hice funcionar", pero solo cuando conozco la cantidad exacta de indices que tiene el array, con un ciclo for, pero no se como ponerle un limite, para que al no haber mas indices, se detenga el ciclo.
for($i = 0; $i<=?;$i++{
ejecucion de la consulta sql para UPDATE. solo me falta saber como poner esa variable que termine el ciclo cuando ya no haya indices en el array a iterar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, agradezco su ayuda y sus sugerencias. Ya pude resolver el problema, lo que tenia que hacer era, en el ciclo for, usar un count($descripcion). y con eso, al no haber mas indices que iterar en los arrays que me llegan por post, se detiene el ciclo y ya no me manda errores y se acutaliza correctamente en la BDD.

```
 $sql ="UPDATE presupuestos_partidas SET partida=:partida, descripcion=:descripcion, 
        cantidad=:cantidad, precio_unitario=:precio_unitario, importe=:importe 
         WHERE id_partida = :id_partida";
 $sql_run = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 for($i = 0; $i < count($descripcion); $i++){

 $sql_exec = $sql_run->execute(array(":partida"=>$partida[$i], 
             ":descripcion"=>$descripcion[$i], ":cantidad"=>$cantidad[$i],
                   ":precio_unitario"=>$precio_unitario[$i],
                   ":importe"=>$importe[$i],":id_partida"=>$id_partida[$i]));
    }
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.